# Ignoring newlines between two words

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

I have a file with a lot of text. Many of these entries look something like this:

```
............word1
word2............
.................
```

I want to count how many times `word1` and `word2` occur in succession <s>ignoring newlines</s> AND with a newline between them.

Example:

```
............word1
word2............
.................
............word1
..word2..........
.................
............word1
word2............
.................
.................
word1word2.......
.................
```

This should give me 2.

I tried using regex in Notepad++ but I'm not too familiar with it.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please add what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `\bword1\Rword2\b`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Count</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b          # word boundary
word1       # word1
\R          # any kind of linebreak
word2       # word2
\b          # word boundary
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a tool like Notepad++ which has counting capability with regex, then you may try searching for the following pattern:

```
\bword1\b[^\r\n]*\bword2\b
```

This would match `word1` followed by anything other than newline characters, followed by `word2`.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that periods and newlines are the only thing separating `word1` from `word2` then this would work:

```
word1\.*[\r\n]+\.*word2
```

https://regex101.com/r/e0aSuy/1